# Laravel3: Loading a content inside a content dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, templating, laravel-3, laravel-blade

I have a form. When user submits the form and gets error, I show it like this:

Register Controller

```
return View::make('theme-admin.user_add')->with('error_msg', validation->errors->first());
```

register.blade.php

```
@if($error_msg !== null)
  <div class="alert red hideit max">
     <div class="left">
            <span class="red-icon"></span>
            <span class="alert-text">{{ $error_msg }}</span> <-- Error message is visible here.
     </div>
     <div class="right">
          <a class="close-red"></a>
     </div>
 </div>
@endif

//
    Actual HTML Form
//
```

However, I want to move that error div into a blade file. (error.blade.php) and I want to call it with parameters when there is an error.

It will look like this.

NEW register.blade.php

```
{{ MESSAGE_CONTENT }} //This should be replaced with error.blade.php dynamically
//
    Actual HTML Form
//
```

MESSAGE_CONTENT will be included via error.blade.php

error.blade.php

```
<div class="alert red hideit max">
     <div class="left">
            <span class="red-icon"></span>
            <span class="alert-text">{{ $message }}</span> <-- Error message is visible here.
     </div>
     <div class="right">
          <a class="close-red"></a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Let's say form failed and I got some errors. I will load error.blade.php so messages will get RED background etc.

Something like this;

```
return View::make('theme-admin.user_add')->with(message_content', (Load error.blade.php here))->with('message', $validation->errors->first();
```

If the form succeeds, I'll just load success.blade.php in messages area and messages will look with GREEN background.

```
 return View::make('theme-admin.user_add')->with(message_content', (Load success.blade.php here))->with('message', 'You successfully registered');
```

You probably got the logic.

How can I do this?

Ps. Image example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipzKY.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I needed Nested Views feature.

```
$view = View::make('home');
$view->nest('content', 'orders', array('orders' => $orders));
```

Refer to Laravel documentation for more information.

Comment: Good you found what you needed, though I´d still reccomend you not create views for displaying error/success messages - and instead redirect as in my example. Nest is simply a shortcut for with() where the second param is used to make a View instance. So in your example where you already have a view instance you cannot nest a new view inside it. See: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/1183

Comment: I haven't tried using the nest yet. If it doesn't load a view within a view and parse child view's variables, I'll use your solution. It's one step better than your solution, and that is, I'll have a fully modular view control on my controllers. Instead of opening adding includes on every view (if / else if / else etc.) I can just have a variable listening for view directly via controller. No more if's or elses. If validation fails, I'll just nest->error. If it passes, I'll just nest->success. Both will be handled via controller. I'm very thankful for your reply, though. It's very enlightening

Comment: Cool, everyone has their preferences I guess. :) Might be possible to hack your way out of the if/else and put your blade template as the second argument for with() or with_errors() - you can atleast put inline html in here, so it should be possible to include a blade template aswell i guess. ie: ->with_errors($validation, static::make('error', $data)); I still prefer the if/else though, it's very clear and I consider those as "presentation-logic" which is better to have in the View, than your Routes. :)

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution may be to have a simple alert object with a type and msg.

```
//in controller
$alert->type = 'error'; // or 'success'
$alert->class = 'red'; // or 'green'
$alert->msg = $validation->errors->first(); // or 'You successfully registered'
 return View::make('theme-admin.user_add')->with('alert', $alert);

//register.blade.php
@include('alert')

//Actual HTML Form

//alert.blade.php
@if(isset($alert))
  <div class="alert {{$alert->class}} hideit max">
     <div class="left">
            <span class="red-icon"></span>
            <span class="alert-text">{{ $alert->msg }}</span>
     </div>
     <div class="right">
          <a class="close-{{$alert->class}}"></a>
     </div>
 </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Not the exact solution I am looking for. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your view (`View::make()`) in a route defined for GET, and then handle your form input in your POST route:

```
//routes.php
Route::get('admin/adduser', array('as' => 'adduser', 'do' => function()
{
    return View::make('theme-admin.user_add');
}));

//route for handling form input
Route::post('register', array('before' => 'csrf', function()
 {
     $rules = array(
         //your vailidation rules here..
     );

     $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

     if ($validation->fails())
     {
         //re-populate form if invalid values, so add flashing input by with_input()
         //also pass errors by using with_errors
         return Redirect::to('adduser')->with_input()->with_errors($validation);
     }
     else {
         //use the named route we defined in Route:get above
         return Redirect:to('adduser')->with('message', 'Successfully added the new user!');
     }
 }));
```

There is no need to create new views for dislaying error and success messages. If you want to seperate your success and error into their own blade templates then you could use the following in your adduser.blade.php:

```
//adduser.blade.php
@if($errors->has())
    @include('errormsg'); //use {{ $errors->first() }} or @foreach($errors->all() as $message) to print error message(s)
@else
    @include('success'); //use {{ $message }} to print success
@endif
```

However you can also use sections in your view, and instead put both the success and error message inside the same view:

```
//feedback.blade.php
@section('error')
    <em class="error">{{ $errors->first() }}</em>
@endsection

@section('success')
    <em class="success">{{ $message }}</em>
@endsection

//adduser.blade.php
@include('feedback');

@if($errors->has())
    @yield('error');
@else
    @yield('success');
@endif
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: There are some cases it will not be included so I can't use @include.

Comment: The thing is, if I use $error_msg !== null, I also have to use $success_msg !== null. This is what I'm using right now. (http://www.eburhan.com/wp-content/ekler/81/demo/) Perhabs something like @include($type) may work, but that's far from what I'm asking.

Comment: I updated my answer with a complete example on how to handle this. Hope that makes things clearer.